# Ext4 Error and disk remounted read-only

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-disk, ext4, fstab

Sometimes I have an error ext4 and my disk becomes read-only.

I can fix it with a reboot and `fcsk /dev/sda2` but it keeps coming back...

Here are some `dmesg` :

```
[ 3160.692730] perf: interrupt took too long (2509 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500                                                                                                                               
[ 3631.408303] perf: interrupt took too long (3144 > 3136), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500                                                                                                                               
[ 4143.729000] perf: interrupt took too long (3992 > 3930), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000                                                                                                                               
[ 4770.574303] perf: interrupt took too long (5018 > 4990), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39750                                                                                                                               
[ 5334.077445] perf: interrupt took too long (6289 > 6272), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 31750                                                                                                                               
[ 8241.921553] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
[11370.110956] perf: interrupt took too long (7918 > 7861), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25250                                                                                                                               
[11484.098212] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0                                                                                                                                                                                      
[11875.568601] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_iget:4862: inode #92441: comm TaskSchedulerFo: bad extra_isize 9489 (inode size 256)
[11875.575273] Aborting journal on device sda2-8.                                                                 
[11875.575537] EXT4-fs error (device sda2) in ext4_da_write_end:3209: IO failure                                  
[11875.575976] EXT4-fs (sda2): Remounting filesystem read-only                                                                       
[11875.576792] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal                 
[11875.577612] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_iget:4862: inode #92441: comm TaskSchedulerFo: bad extra_isize 9489 (inode size 256)
[11875.583499] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_iget:4862: inode #92441: comm TaskSchedulerFo: bad extra_isize 9489 (inode size 256)
[11875.832886] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_iget:4862: inode #92441: comm TaskSchedulerFo: bad extra_isize 9489 (inode size 256)
[11899.686408] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 614 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686483] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 705 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686587] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 614 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686656] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 705 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686719] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 614 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686781] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 705 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686844] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 614 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system                   
[11899.686938] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 705 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.686999] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 614 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[11899.687084] systemd-journald[395]: Failed to write entry (21 items, 705 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
```

And my `/etc/fstab` :

```
UUID=9c882ba5-b980-4f7d-dd02-cd0a1831ab1a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=0E37-D0A2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Should I remove or change `remount-ro` in `fstab` and ignore this error ? How to fix / avoid this error ?

Comment: If this keeps happening even after a `fsck` and a reboot, then something is corrupting the data in your filesystem. It may be a faulty disk (is it SSD? with a normal disk you'd get more errors...) or maybe your system has bad memory where memory is being corrupted. Either way, ignoring such errors is a recipe to completely destroy your data.

Comment: ssd on a laptop ~6 months old

Comment: Another possible cause is bad RAM - the buffer for a particular part of the ext4 FS is likely to end up in a similar place, and if the underlying RAM is bad, it can get corrupted. I had a similar case about a year ago (though other effects, not the FS), and it was hard to diagnose - memtest86+ didn't find errors. Changing the RAM solved it. And sometimes laptops get used parts like RAM, even if sold "new"...

Comment: You can delete read-only bit via `hdparm` : `hdparm -r0 /dev/sda`

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173738/crash-systemd-journal-failed-to-write-entry-ignoring-read-only-file-system-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your disk for bad sectors or bad blocks? you can use **badblocks** or **smartctl** command to check in linux, I think bad disk is only reason for your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Apparently the disk had nothing wrong. I learned to live with it for a while but after few months the problem solved itself. I don't remember what, maybe a kernel upgrade.